# Ocaml - matching two lists

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml, type-inference, operator-precedence

I am trying to write a shuffle function in OCaml, but there is a problem with type inference. Merlin tells me that `l1` and `l2` are of type `'a list list`, which is not true because they are only `'a list`. Why does it claims that?

```
let shuffle l1 l2 =
  let rec scan l1 l2 acc =
    match (l1, l2) with
    | [],[] -> acc
    | ([],h2::t2) -> scan [] t2 h2::acc
    | (h1::t1, []) -> scan t1 [] h1::acc
    | (h1::t1,h2::t2) -> scan t1 t2 h1::h2::acc
  in scan l1 l2 []
;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is that operator precedence isn't determined by your grouping by whitespace. That is, `scan [] t2 h2::acc` is interpreted as `(scan [] t2 h2)::acc`, not `scan [] t2 (h2::acc)`, because function application has a higher precedence than `::`. The fix is simply to add parentheses where appropriate.

See [this table](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html) for the precedence and associativity of the different operators in OCaml.